# Visualforce apex:chart showing unknown property error

Tags: visualforce, charts, visualforce-charting

I am trying to display a simple line chart with 3 data (today, 7 days ago, and 14 days ago) in order to view the evolution of the score of a certain record. Everything is set to "public"... the error is:

**Property BC_ScoreCardActor.estosDatos unknown**

Here is the Controller:

```
public class BC_ScoreCardActor {
    public List<Data> obtenerData(){
        return BC_ScoreCardActor.obtenerDatosGrafico();
    }
    @RemoteAction
    public static List<Data> obtenerDatosRemotos(){
        return BC_ScoreCardActor.obtenerDatosGrafico();
    }
    
    public static List<Data> obtenerDatosGrafico(){
        {yada yada}
        List<Data> estosDatos = new List<Data>();
        estosDatos.add(new Data(hoy_2, puntos_hoy_2));
        estosDatos.add(new Data(hoy_1, puntos_hoy_1));
        estosDatos.add(new Data(hoy_0, puntos_hoy_0));
        return estosDatos;
    }
    
    public class Data {
        public Date fecha {get;set;}
        public Double puntaje {get; set;}
        public Data(Date fecha, Double puntaje) {
            this.fecha = fecha;
            this.puntaje = puntaje;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="BC_ScoreCardActor">
    <apex:chart data="{!estosDatos}" height="600" width="400">
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="fecha" title="Fecha"></apex:axis>
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="puntaje" title="Puntaje"></apex:axis>
        <apex:lineSeries axis="left" fill="false" xField="fecha" yField="puntaje"></apex:lineSeries>
    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Visualforce, you are referring to `estosDatos`, however that variable is not visible to the page. It is only declared within the scope of the `obtenerDatosGrafico` method.

To make this work, you will need a getter in your controller and then reference that in your Visualforce.

For example:

```
public List<Data> getMyData() { ... }
```

And

```
<apex:chart data="{!myData}" height="400" width="500">
```

So in your example, rename `obtenerData` to `getEstosDatos`.

Comment: So simple... changed to getEstosDatos and voilá. THX!!!